# Is this true? If ‎$‎\varphi\in ‎\mathcal{B}_{‎\mathcal{A}}(E,F)‎$‎ and preserving density, then $‎\varphi‎$‎ is surjection

Tags: banach-algebras

Is this true? If ‎$‎\varphi\in ‎\mathcal{B}_{‎\mathcal{A}}(E,F)‎$‎ and preserving density, then $‎\varphi‎$‎ is surjection, why?. Such that $E$ and $F$ are right Hilbert  ‎$‎‎‎\mathcal{A}‎$‎-modules and $\mathcal{B}_{‎\mathcal{A}}(E,F)‎$‎ is the set of all bounded $‎‎‎\mathcal{A}‎$-linear operator from $E$ to $F$. (  $\varphi‎ :‎E\longrightarrow F$ is called $‎\mathcal‎{‎‎A‎}‎$-linear if it is linear‎ and for each $a\in ‎\mathcal‎{‎‎A‎}‎$ and $x\in E$‎, ‎$\varphi(xa)=\varphi(x)a$ ). Also ‎we say that $‎\varphi\in ‎\mathcal{B}_{‎\mathcal{A}}(E,F)‎$ preserves density on ‎$‎E‎$‎ if the subset $B$ of ‎$‎E‎$ ‎is‎ dense in $E$, then‎ ‎$\varphi (B)$ is dense in $F$.

My answer: Let $A=\mathbb{C}, E=F=L^2[0,1]$ and $(\varphi f)x=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$. Is it true?

Comment: Why did you post this again?

Comment: This is a different question. Pay attention to properties of E,F,BA(E,F) and φ